# Schema.org deliveryLeadTime unitCode for Business Days

Tags: schema.org

I'm trying to add schema.org markup for product availability on a product that has a 7-10 business day shipping lead time. I found an option for this in Offer>deliveryLeadTime

One of the properties of deliveryLeadTime is unitCode (http://schema.org/deliveryLeadTime) which expects a 3digit code. Using this reference: http://www.unece.org/fileadmin/DAM/cefact/recommendations/rec20/rec20_Rev9e_2014.xls I've found E49 for 'working day' in Annex 2 (or Annex 3?).

E49 looks like what I need but I'm looking for anyone who has knowledge of whether that's the proper code for 'Business Day' in the context of Schema.org markup and if search engines (mostly Google) seem to understand this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I don't claim to be an expert in the use of UN/CEFACT codes, but based on that spreadsheet, it looks like E49 is the correct code for "working day".  So, you could possibly format it something like this:

```
  <div itemprop="deliveryLeadTime" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/QuantitativeValue">
    <span itemprop="minValue">7</span> -
    <span itemprop="maxValue">10</span> <span>working days</span>
    <meta itemprop="unitCode" content="E49" />
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks @daviddeering That's the solution I went with too and I guess we'll be watching Google to see if it picks up on it in the coming weeks.